# Row selection does not call didSelectRow after reloading all components in that UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipickerview

Let's say for instance that I have a `UIPickerView` in my `ViewController`. Upon launch I use this code here:

```
[picker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

After selecting the row that I want, why doesn't it trigger the `didSelectRow` code?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {}
```

Any ideas on why this is and how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to fix this was to just add a blank row and the picker loaded to the blank row. This forces the user to slide the `UIPickerView` so the `didSelectRow` get triggered.